# When was Screaming vocals actually invented, and by whom?

Tags: technique, voice

I have heard many different tales and stories of who invented the scream in music. From the likes of people saying the Led Zeppelin, Motörhead and Ozzy Osbourne era of metal were the ones to introduce it, to people saying it was invented in new-wave metal and post-hardcore, such as Bullet for my Valentine, Trivium, Disturbed and so on...

What I want to know is in the history books of metal and any other genres, when was screaming introduced?

Is it specific to one artist who created it?

If so, which artist was this?

Also comments on how and why it was introduced and used would be helpful.

Comment: Screaming the entire vocal of a song, yes?

Comment: no just the scream itself when it first appeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Screaming in vocals has been around much longer than popular music.  Many singers in many genres have had screaming in some vocalization they have done to provide emphasis to a phrasing or a lyric.  See composer Alban Berg as an opera example.

But if we are to stick to popular rock music like metal, during the 50's you had people like Little Richard and Jerry Lee Lewis doing quite a lot of screaming and in the sixties, the classic "metal" screaming falsetto was done a lot by singers like Ian Gillan, Janis Joplin and Roger Daltrey.

Comment: Screaming Jay Hawkins.   Lightning Hopkins.

Comment: Oh yeah... Screamin' Jay Hawkins.  King Diamond's grandaddy.  LOL!